# errors says there have been some errors whereas i almost completely copy and paste the google tutorial code

Tags: python, neural-network

Those are the complete errors, and I am so confused about what it is trying to say. I was doing a tutorial from google, and I almost completely copy the code from the tutorial but replace its dataset with my own dataset, and those errors occur.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\julia\Anaconda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2897, in get_loc
        return self._engine.get_loc(key)
      File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
      File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
      File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1607, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
      File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
    KeyError: 'Objective 1'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/julia/Anaconda/envs/myenv/Mycode.py", line 333, in <module>
    validation_targets=validation_targets)
  File "C:/Users/julia/Anaconda/envs/myenv/Mycode.py", line 288, in train_nn_regression_model
    steps=steps_per_period
  File "C:\Users\julia\Anaconda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 367, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "C:\Users\julia\Anaconda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1158, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "C:\Users\julia\Anaconda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1185, in _train_model_default
    input_fn, ModeKeys.TRAIN))
  File "C:\Users\julia\Anaconda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1022, in _get_features_and_labels_from_input_fn
    self._call_input_fn(input_fn, mode))
  File "C:\Users\julia\Anaconda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1113, in _call_input_fn
    return input_fn(**kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/julia/Anaconda/envs/myenv/Mycode.py", line 268, in <lambda>
    training_targets["Objective 1"],
  File "C:\Users\julia\Anaconda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2980, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\julia\Anaconda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2899, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1607, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Objective 1'
```

I was a machine learning beginner, and when I use python and follow the codes from google machine learning tutorial, some errors came up, and I am not sure what is going on.

```
# Step 1 - Set up and import necessary packages
from __future__ import print_function
import math

from IPython import display
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib import gridspec
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import metrics
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.data import Dataset

tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(tf.compat.v1.logging.ERROR)
pd.options.display.max_rows = 10
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.1f}'.format

# Step 2 - Load our data
zerlite_13X_error = pd.read_csv("zerlite_13x_error.csv", sep=",")

# print(zerlite_13X_error.head())  # Load data done

# We will randomize data. just to be sure not to get any pathological ordering effects the
# performance of Stochastic Gradient Descent. And we first consider objective 1

zerlite_13X_error = zerlite_13X_error.reindex(
    np.random.permutation(zerlite_13X_error.index))


# Define features and Configure columns
# Define features which are parameters 1 to parameters 8
def preprocess_features(zerlite_13X_error):
    """Prepares input features from zerlite_13X_error
    Args:
    zerlite_13X_error: A Pandas DataFrame expected to contain data

    Return:
    A DataFrame that contains the features to be used for the model.
    including synthetic features
    """
    selected_features = zerlite_13X_error[
        ["Parameter 1",
         "Parameter 2",
         "Parameter 3",
         "Parameter 4",
         "Parameter 5",
         "Parameter 6",
         "Parameter 7",
         "Parameter 8"]]
    processed_features = selected_features.copy()
    # print(processed_features.head())
    return processed_features


def preprocess_targets(zerlite_13X_error):
    """Prepares target features (i.e. labels) from zerlite_13X_error set

    Args:
    zerlite_13X_error: A Panda dataframe that was expected to contain data from
    the zerolite_13X_error data set

    Returns:
    A dataframe that contains the target feature
    """
    output_targets = pd.DataFrame()
    # Create the output targets
    output_targets["Objective 1"] = zerlite_13X_error["Objective 1"]
    print(output_targets.head())
    return output_targets


# For training Set, we will choose 14000 out of 20154 number, about 70% of data as training set
training_examples = preprocess_features(zerlite_13X_error.head(14000))
training_examples.describe()
print('-- Training Examples Describe --')
print(training_examples.describe())

training_targets = preprocess_targets(zerlite_13X_error.head(14000))
training_targets.describe()
print('-- Training Targets Describe --')
print(training_targets.describe())

# For Validation Set, we will choose 3000 examples, out of total 20154 examples
validation_examples = preprocess_features(zerlite_13X_error.iloc[14001:17001])
validation_examples.describe()
print('-- Validation Examples Describe --')
print(validation_examples.describe())

validation_targets = preprocess_targets(zerlite_13X_error.iloc[14001:17001])
validation_targets.describe()
print('-- Validation Targets Describe --')
print(validation_targets.describe())

# for Test Set, we will choose the last 3154 examples
test_examples = preprocess_features((zerlite_13X_error.tail(3154)))
test_examples.describe()
print('-- Test Examples Describe --')
print(test_examples.describe())

test_targets = preprocess_targets(zerlite_13X_error.tail(3154))
test_targets.describe()
print('-- Test Targets Describe --')
print(test_targets.describe())



# As we are now working with multiple features, modularize the code for configuring columns into a
# separate function
def construct_feature_columns(input_features):
    """Construct the TensorFlow columns:

    Args:
        input_features: The name of numerical input features to use
    Returns:
        A set of feature columns
    """
    return set([tf.feature_column.numeric_column(my_feature)
                for my_feature in input_features])


# Train and evaluate the model
def my_input_fn(features, targets, batch_size=1, shuffle=True, num_epochs=None):
    """Trains a linear regression model of multiple features
    Args:
        features: pandas DataFrame of features
        targets: pandas DataFrame of targets
        batch_size: Size of batches to be passed to the model
        shuffle: True or False. Whether to shuffle the data
        num_epochs: Number of epochs for which data should be repeated. None = Repeat indefinitely
    Returns:
        Tuple of (features, labels) for next data batch
    """
    # Convert pandas data into a dict of np arrays
    features = {key: np.array(value) for key, value in dict(features).items()}

    # Construct a dataset, and configure batching/repeating
    ds = Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, targets))  # Warning: 2GB limit
    ds = ds.batch(batch_size).repeat(num_epochs)

    # Shuffle the data, if specified
    if shuffle:
        ds = ds.shuffle(10000)

    # Return the next batch of data
    features, labels = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
    return features, labels


# Now we will go creating a train model using neural network
def train_nn_regression_model(learning_rate, steps, batch_size, hidden_units,
                              training_examples, training_targets,
                              validation_examples, validation_targets):
    """Trains a neural network regression model of multiple features

    In addition to training, this function also prints training progress information,
    as well as plot of the training and validation loss over time

    Args:
        learning_rate: A 'float', the learning rate
        steps: A non-zero 'int', the total number of training steps. A training step
               consists of a forward and backward pass using a single batch.
        batch_size: A non-zero 'int', the batch size.
        hidden_size" A 'list' of int values, specifying the number of neurons in each layer
        training_examples: A 'DataFrame' containing one or more columns from
                          'zerlite_13X_error' to use as input features for training
        training_targets: A 'DataFrame' containing exactly one column from
                          'zerlite_13X_error' to use as target for training
        validation_examples: A 'DataFrame' containing one or more columns from
                          'zerlite_13X_error' to use as input features for validation
        validation_targets: A 'DataFrame' containing exactly one column from
                          'zerlite_13X_error' to use as target for validation

    Returns:
        A 'DNNRegressor' object trained on the training data.
    """

    periods = 10
    steps_per_period = steps / periods

    # Create a DNNRegressor Object
    my_optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    my_optimizer = tf.contrib.estimator.clip_gradients_by_norm(my_optimizer, 5.0)
    dnn_regressor = tf.estimator.DNNRegressor(
        feature_columns=construct_feature_columns(training_examples),
        hidden_units=hidden_units,
        optimizer=my_optimizer,
    )

    # Create input functions.
    training_input_fn = lambda: my_input_fn(training_examples,
                                            training_targets["Objective 1"],
                                            batch_size=batch_size)
    predict_training_input_fn = lambda: my_input_fn(training_examples,
                                                    training_targets["Objective 1"],
                                                    num_epochs=1,
                                                    shuffle=False)
    predict_validation_input_fn = lambda: my_input_fn(validation_examples,
                                                      validation_targets["Objective 1"],
                                                      num_epochs=1,
                                                      shuffle=False)

    # Train the model, but do so inside a loop so that we can periodically assess loss metrics
    print("Training Models ............")
    print("RMSE (on training data): ")
    training_rmse = []
    validation_rmse = []
    for period in range(0, periods):   # Python shows error occuring here 
        # Train the model, starting from the prior state
        dnn_regressor.train(
            input_fn=training_input_fn,
            steps=steps_per_period)
        # take a break and compute predictions
        training_predictions = dnn_regressor.predict(input_fn=predict_training_input_fn)
        training_predictions = np.array([item['predictions'][0] for item in training_predictions])

        validation_predictions = dnn_regressor.predict(input_fn=predict_validation_input_fn)
        validation_predictions = np.array([item['predictions'][0] for item in validation_predictions])

        # Compute training and validation loss
        training_root_mean_squared_error = math.sqrt(
            metrics.mean_squared_error(training_predictions, training_targets))
        validation_root_mean_squared_error = math.sqrt(
            metrics.mean_squared_error(validation_predictions, validation_targets))

        # Occasionally print the current loss
        print("  period %02d: %02f" % (period, training_root_mean_squared_error))

        # Add the loss metrics from this period to our list
        training_rmse.append(training_root_mean_squared_error)
        validation_rmse.append(validation_root_mean_squared_error)
    print("Model training finished")

    # Output a graph of loss metrics over periods
    plt.ylabel("RMSE")
    plt.xlabel("Periods")
    plt.title("Root Mean Squared Error v.s. Periods")
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.plot(training_rmse, label="training")
    plt.plot(validation_rmse, label="validation")
    plt.legend()
    print("Final RMSE (on training data):  %0.2f" % training_root_mean_squared_error)
    print("Final RMSE (on validation data): %0.2f" % validation_root_mean_squared_error)

    return dnn_regressor


# Train NN model
dnn_regressor = train_nn_regression_model(
    learning_rate=0.1,
    steps=5000,
    batch_size=10,
    hidden_units=[10, 2],
    training_examples=training_examples,
    training_targets=training_targets,
    validation_examples=validation_examples,
    validation_targets=validation_targets) # Python shows error here
```

Comment: have you checked your Python version as well as the sklearn, tensor flow versions?

Comment: Hi, I have checked it, the Python version is 3.7, the sklearn version is 0.21.3, and the TensorFlow version should be 1.14.0. Not quite sure what I should do after this. Do I need to update them or anything else cuz it seems like they are all the latest versions.

Comment: This is odd cuz when I copy and paste the code from google tutorial, it works fine, but when it comes to my own code, it fails even though I thought that my code is pretty much the same as the one in the tutorial except some parameters name and target name.

Comment: Please [edit] the post with the complete error, since you only posted the beginning of the Traceback.

Comment: Have edited it already, sorry for the vagueness before.